# How to update fields in Firestore map

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Don't know how to go about adding new fields into a map in Firestore using a variable rather then a hardcoded field name.

I have a data structure in firestorm. The collection is called webQuiz and the document is called '12345. The data structure looks like:

```
    roomName: Demo0
    roomNumber: 46532
    people:{11111:"David, 22222:"Peter}
```

Note that people is a map data object.

I would like to add another field to the people map. The code below works but instead of the data looking like 
`people:{11111:"David, 22222:"Peter, 44444:"Cathy"}` it looks like
`people:{11111:"David, 22222:"Peter, x:"Cathy"}`

How can I use a variable which holds the field name in this situation? The x should be a variable but it is picked up literally as a property.

```
    function testing(){

      var x = "44444"
      var y = "Cathy"

      var cityRef = db.collection('webQuiz').doc('12345');

    var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
      people: {x: y}
    }, { merge: true });
```

I expect the output in firestorm to be
people:`{11111:"David, 22222:"Peter, 44444:"Cathy"}` but the actual output at the moment is
people:`{11111:"David, 22222:"Peter, x:"Cathy"}`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the full field path as the key of the update:

```
var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
  `people.${x}`: y
});
```

This will prevent re-writing the entire "people" field, since you are specifying which property of the map to change directly.

Note that the field name and the property name are separated by a period.

Comment: I actually found another solution which works just as well.                                
          function testing(){
  var cityRef = db.collection('webBuzzer').doc('12345');
  var x = "55555";
  var y = "Luke";
  var updateObj = {
    people: {}
  };
  updateObj.people[x] = y;
  var setWithMerge = cityRef.set(updateObj, { merge: true }); Anyway - thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because I'm using typescript, but this throws an exception. When I do `[\`people.${x}\`]: y` it doesn't throw an exception, but it creates a field within the document of that string rather than updating a field.

Comment: @joshpetit : I've the same here